# Extract graph image using PhantomJs

Tags: phantomjs, jspdf

I use jqplot to create a complex data graph for a clinical web application using IE7.  Now, I need to create a PDF and the graph is part of the PDF.
Since it is IE7, I can't export jqplot graph as an image.

My plan is:

1. From the web app, user clicks on a button to send the graph data (JSON) to a web service on a remote server.
2. On the remote server, I will have a HTML page to be built dynamically by PhantomJS using the JSON data passed to the web service.
3. When the page load is complete, I will "rasterize ??" the page to get the graph image.
4. I will use this image in building my PDF using package like jsPDF.
5. Return the PDF URI back to the web app.

Does this make any sense at all?  I struggle on how to integrate all the moving parts together. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. What kind of answer do you expect? PhantomJS can render to PDF. There is no need to use jsPDF.